# How to open a browser when the TextEdit::onLinkActivated signal is received

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml, qt5

I'd like to open a browser window to display the URL received by a TextEdit [onLinkActivated](https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-1.0/QtQuick.TextEdit/#onLinkActivated-signal) signal.

Is it possible to perform such call from the QML application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call [Qt.openUrlExternally](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#openUrlExternally-method)(link) in the onLinkActivated signal handler:

```
onLinkActivated:  {
    Qt.openUrlExternally(link)
}
```

It will attempt to open the specified target url in an external application, based on the user's desktop preferences.