# How do open a link with a button

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, programming, qml

I would like to click a button in my QML app and have it open a link in the browser on the device.

Comment: Close voters: This most certainly is about Ubuntu, it is about QML development for Ubuntu and/or Ubuntu Touch.

Comment: Related: [How to open a browser when the TextEdit::onLinkActivated signal is received](http://askubuntu.com/questions/438445/how-to-open-a-browser-when-the-texteditonlinkactivated-signal-is-received/438446#438446)

Answer (score 2):

```
onClicked: { Qt.openUrlExternally("http://bbc.co.uk/"); }
```